# failed to send "proto.005-PsBABY5H.contract.cannot_pay_storage_fee"

Tags: fees

when i try to make transaction to other account
[image]
[operatin link](https://zeronet.tzstats.com/opSfmBLn9JrByExGHosaM1rWpW2XqVYCQMNafP4FiwuE65A3X2H)

Answer (score 1):

The storage fee is higher than the contract balance

Id : proto.005-PsBabyM1.contract.cannot_pay_storage_fee
Category : temporary

[link](https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/errors.html)

Comment: please edit your answer to reference the Tezos documentation and not some other chain's docs.

Comment: @utdrmac feel free to edit the answer as appropriate